# php socket_recvfrom multithreading

Tags: php, multithreading

I have a problem of waiting socket_recvfrom to receive something otherwise the script won't continue running

```
for( $i= 1024 ; $i <= 65535 ; $i++ ) {
$sock[$i] = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($sock[$i], $sourceips['madcoder'],$i);
socket_connect($sock[$i], '115.188.58.144 ', 1195);
$request = 'data';
socket_write($sock[$i], $request);
$from = '';
$port = 0;
$valeur = socket_recvfrom($sock[$i], $buf, 1222, 0, $from, $port);
}
```

this code basically send a udp request on a different local port each time and see if he got a response 
The pogramme now is stuck waiting to receive a packet thanks to  socket_recvfrom

I want to make it run as fast as i could without risking to lose a response

i could use

```
socket_set_option($sock[$i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
```

but the problem is waiting for over a 1 second is too much and there is a problem with setting a value of under a second

changing the value to

```
array('sec' => 0, 'usec' => 100)
```

or

```
array('sec' => 0.1, 'usec' => 0)
```

won't work
 so i was thinking of multi threading ,The only way  i know to multi thread is a "for" loop like i did 
but i really wish if i could try something else more effective

Comment: Read about [`socket_select()`](http://php.net/socket_select) and [`socket_set_blocking()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php).

Answer (score 0):

using pthreads, http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php , something like

```
<?php
class async_sender extends Thread {
public function __construct($i,$sourceip){
  $this->i=$i;
  $this->sourceip=$sourceip;
}
 public $sourceip;
 public $finished=false;
 public $response='';
 public $socket=NULL;
 public $i=-1;
public function run(){
    $this->socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    socket_bind($this->socket, $this->sourceip,$this->i);
    socket_connect($this->socket, '115.188.58.144 ', 1195);
    $request = 'data';
    socket_write($this->socket, $request);
    $from = '';
    $port = 0;

    socket_recvfrom($this->socket, $this->response, 1222, 0, $from, $port);
    $this->finished=true;

}
}

$sender_threads=array();
for( $i= 1024 ; $i <= 65535 ; $i++ ) {
$sender_threads[$i]=new async_sender($i,$sourceips['madcoder']);
$sender_threads[$i]->start();
}
```

Comment: This only avoids the problem by using a different approach, but it does not solve the problem nor is it an explanation. A better answer would contain explanation and solutions including `socket_select()` or other polling mechanism and the difference between blocking and non-blocking sockets. Also, pthreads is only available for PHP built with zend thread-safety enabled.